# Существует ли stl функция которая позволяет перемешивать элементы контейнера случайным образом?

Tags: c++, stl

Или такую функцию нужно писать самому?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все есть - [shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/?kw=shuffle). Главное, немного поискать.

Comment: спасибо как всегда выручили

Answer (score 2):

Для этого подойдёт `std::random_shuffle`.